# Response assertion for json response in jmeter for webservice

Tags: web-services, jmeter, web-api-testing

As i am new to webservice in jmeter ,I am not understand how to move ahead in this, I have a json response like below,How can i put assertion for the below...

```
{
  "flightDetails": [
    {
      "outBoundFlights": [
        {
          "flightInfo": {
            "departureCity": "Bengaluru, , IN - Kempegowda International Airport",
            "departureDateAndTime": "2017-04-24T17:00:00",
            "arrivalCity": "Newark, NJ, US - Newark Liberty Intl Arpt",
            "arrivalDateAndTime": "2017-04-25T07:55:00",
            "numberOfStops": 1,
            "individualPricing": [
              {
                "passengerType": 1,
                "totalTaxFeePerPaxType": 626.55,
                "totalTaxAmountPerPaxType": 461.55,
                "baseFareAmountPerPaxType": 165.0,
                "taxandFee": {
                  "markup": 6.6,
                  "merchantFee": 40.99,
                  "supplierTax": 410.96
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add response assertion in your HTTP request and add all JSON responce in Pattern to test field

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project like:

- Given you need to check whether `departureCity` equals `"Bengaluru, , IN - Kempegowda International Airport`
- Add JSON Path Assertion as a child of the request returning your JSON response
- Configure it as follows:

  [image: JMeter JSON Path Assertion]
- If everything is fine the result will be successful
- If expected value won't match the actual the sampler will be marked as failed:

  [image: JSON Path Asertion Failure]

JSON Path Assertion can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)